# Background does not show properly

Tags: html, css

For my Sign In form I have added buttons Sign In with facebook and google.

Basically, copy/pasted from codepen. 
HTML:

```
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--facebook">   Login with Facebook </button>

<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--google">   Login with Google </button>
```

CSS:

```
body { padding: 2em; }


/* Shared */
.loginBtn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  /* width: 13em;  - apply for fixed size */
  margin: 0.2em;
  padding: 0 15px 0 46px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 34px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.loginBtn:before {
  content: "";
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 100%;
}
.loginBtn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.loginBtn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 32px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}


/* Facebook */
.loginBtn--facebook {
  background-color: #4C69BA;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#4C69BA, #3B55A0);
  /*font-family: "Helvetica neue", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #354C8C;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:before {
  border-right: #364e92 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_facebook.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--facebook:hover,
.loginBtn--facebook:focus {
  background-color: #5B7BD5;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#5B7BD5, #4864B1);
}


/* Google */
.loginBtn--google {
  /*font-family: "Roboto", Roboto, arial, sans-serif;*/
  background: #DD4B39;
}
.loginBtn--google:before {
  border-right: #BB3F30 1px solid;
  background: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/14082/icon_google.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--google:hover,
.loginBtn--google:focus {
  background: #E74B37;
}
```

Using the same code above I decided to add Twitter button as well. I changed the color etc., however when I change background to the TWITTER logo, I does not show on the page and I can't understand why. My code for twitter button:
HTML

```
<button class="loginBtn loginBtn--twitter"><%= link_to "Sign in with Twitter", sign_in_with_twitter_path, class: 'text-light' %></button>
```

CSS:

```
    /* Twitter */
.loginBtn--twitter {
  background-color: #53ADE9;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#53ADE9, #53ADE9);
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #53ADE9;
}
.loginBtn--twitter:before {
  border-right: #3a90c9 1px solid;
  background: url('http://p10cdn4static.sharpschool.com/UserFiles/Servers/Server_208743/Image/twitter2.png') 6px 6px no-repeat;
}
.loginBtn--twitter:hover,
.loginBtn--twitter:focus {
  background-color: #70bcef;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#70bcef, #70bcef);
}
```

Why background property with my URL does not apply?

Comment: Did you see any error in your browser's console?

Comment: fiddle would help speed up getting solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Your twitter picture is big. really big.

Check my example here - https://jsfiddle.net/ta0emnmh/

Your twitter style should be like this:

```
.loginBtn--twitter:before {
    border-right: #3a90c9 1px solid;
    background: url(http://p10cdn4static.sharpschool.com/UserFiles/Servers/Server_208743/Image/twitter2.png) 1px 4px no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}
```